# child component cannot access function that is passed down with context hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I was playing around with the react context hooks API and am having trouble with this function I am passing through my provider but the child component seems to not be able to run it.

The following is my app.js file

```
// import "./App.css";
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Test from "./Test"

import {ThemeContext,ThemeUpdateContext} from "./Contexts";


function App() {
  const [logged, setLogged] = useState(false);
  
  
  function connectRoom(){
    console.log("hello");
    setLogged(true);
  }
  return (
   
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={logged}>
      <ThemeUpdateContext.Provider value={connectRoom}>
        <Test />
      </ThemeUpdateContext.Provider>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

The following is my Contexts.js file where I created my contexts.

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const ThemeContext = createContext(null);
export const ThemeUpdateContext = createContext(null);
```

The following is my Test.js file where I have made a simple login/log out page that switches when the button is clicked.

```
import React from 'react'
import {ThemeContext,ThemeUpdateContext} from './Contexts'

export default function Test() {

    const {logged} = React.useContext(ThemeContext)
    const {connectRoom} = React.useContext(ThemeUpdateContext)
    
    return (
        <div>
           {!logged ? (
        <h1> not logged</h1>
      ):(<h1>logged</h1>)}

      <button onClick={connectRoom}> click me</button> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is what the Test.js component looks like:
[image]

I need help understanding why the page does not switch to logged in when I click the button, and why it doesn't console.log anything when I click it.

Comment: Always check the docs first: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext The example line is `const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);`

Answer (score 1):

```
<ThemeContext.Provider value={logged}>
// ...
const {logged} = React.useContext(ThemeContext)
```

When you consume the context, you're destructuring it as though you expect an object with a `.logged` property, but that's not what you've provided. You've just provided the value directly, which is a boolean. So you're effectively trying to access `(false).logged`, which is undefined. A similar issue happens with your other context as well.

The fix is to consume them like this:

```
const logged = React.useContext(ThemeContext)
const connectRoom = React.useContext(ThemeUpdateContext)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm new to react so I'm still making these silly mistakes :(